# How to get Photos from iOS library and show them on Map (mapkit)

Tags: swift, mapkit, photos

I need to fetch images from the library and add a tappable preview on the [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOdgz.pn).
I already managed to add the pins but I **can't fetch the related photos** and show them.

This is the code I wrote with the Photos Framework

```
    let resultCollections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.Moment, subtype: .Any, options: nil)

    resultCollections.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({
        (object, index, stop) -> Void in


        let collection = object as! PHAssetCollection


        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
        formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle


        var date =  collection.startDate
        var location = collection.approximateLocation?.coordinate


        // ADD PIN
        if location != nil {

            let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(date!)

            let annotationOne = CustomPointAnnotation()
            annotationOne.coordinate = location!
            annotationOne.title = dateString
            annotationOne.pinCustomImageName = "pin.png"
            annotationOne.belongTo = collection
            annotationOne.image = UIImage(named:annotationOne.pinCustomImageName)

            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotationOne)

        }
    })
```